# JavaScript regex for password containing at least 6 characters, 1 number, 1 letter, any special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying like this:

`(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}$/)`

but it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your can use `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]).{6,}$/` .

1. `(?=.*\d)` for at least one digit
2. `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` for at least one letter
3. `(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?])` for at least one special character

Use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** to find pattern

```js
$('#text').keyup(function() {
  $(this).css('border', this.value.match(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]).{6,}$/) ? '5px solid green' : '5px solid red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

Or you can also use **[`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)** to find match

```js
$('#text').keyup(function() {
  var re = new RegExp(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]).{6,}$/);
  $(this).css('border', re.test(this.value) ? '5px solid green' : '5px solid red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
```

Comment: Case problem - doesn't match for `abc1ef`. I would suggest `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,}$/` or `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}$/i`

Comment: /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,}$/

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the parenthesis from around the opening and closing `/` in your regular expression.

Also, it is possible you wanted to combine the `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` into `[a-zA-Z]` so that both upper and lower case letters don't have to found, just one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `String.prototype.match`

```js
var str1 = "abc1e.";

var str2 = "abc1e ";
// match special character; any character not digit , 
// not any alphanumeric character , including `_` , 
// not space character
var res1 = str1.match(/[^\d|\w|\s]/i);
// if match found , concat digit , alphanumeric character
// if resulting array length is 6 , return `true` , else return `false`
res1 = !!res1 ? res1[0].concat(str1.match(/\d+|\w+/i)).length === 6 : false;

var res2 = str2.match(/[^\d|\w|\s]/i);
res2 = !!res2 ? res2[0].concat(str1.match(/\d+|\w+/i)).length === 6 : false;

console.log(res1, res2);
```